# how to improve computation speed when finding max in a large list? excluding Numpy

Tags: python-3.x

consider a game with an array(=num) containing some integers. I can take any integer and remove it from the array and add half of that number (rounded up) back to the array.i can do it for a fixed number of moves(=k).
the challenge is to minimize the sum of the final array.

my problem is that the test cases fail when dealing with large arrays :(

what is the efficient computation way to overcome this?

my first step for the challenge is taking max(num) and replace it with the result of ceil(max(num)/2) for k times.
another option is using sort(reverse) in every loop and replace the last value.
I've played with different sorting algos, read here and try bisect module they are all very new to me and didn't overcome the test-cases threshold, so i hope someone here can provide a helping hand for a newbie.

```
def minSum(num, k):
    for i in range(k):
        num.sort(reverse=True)
        num.insert(0, math.ceil(num[0] / 2))
        num.remove(num[1])
    return sum(num)


minSum([10,20,7],4)
>>> 14
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, inserting at the beginning of a Python `list` is much slower than inserting at the end, since every element has to be moved. Also, there's absolutely no reason to do so in the first place. You could just sort without `reverse=True`, then use `pop` to remove and return the last item and `bisect.insort` to put it back in at the right place without needing to re-sort the whole list.

```
from bisect import insort
from math import ceil

def min_sum(num, k):
    num.sort()
    for i in range(k):
        largest = num.pop()
        insort(num, ceil(largest/2))
    return sum(num)
```

This should already be significantly faster than your original approach. However, in the worst case this is still `O(n lg n)` for the sort and `O(k*n)` for the processing; if your input is constructed such that halving each successive largest element makes it the new smallest element, you'll end up inserting it at the start which incurs an `O(n)` memory movement.

We can do better by using a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) approach, implemented in Python by the [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) library. You can `heapify` a list in linear time, and then use `heapreplace` to remove and replace the largest element successively. A slight awkwardness here is that `heapq` only implements a min-heap, so we'll need an extra pass to negate our input list at the beginning. One bonus side-effect is that since we now need to round down instead of up, we can just use integer division instead of `math.ceil`.

```
from heapq import heapify, heapreplace

def min_sum(num, k):
    for i in range(len(num)):
        num[i] = -num[i]
    heapify(num)
    for i in range(k):
        largest = num[0]
        heapreplace(num, largest // 2)
    return -sum(num)
```

This way the initial list negation and heapification takes `O(n)`, and then processing is only `O(k lg n)` since each `heapreplace` is a `lg n` operation.

Comment: WOW amazing!! heapify shredded all of the test-cases.
will read more on that later...
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To add some timing to all of the algorithms, it looks like @tzaman's heapq algorithm is by far the fastest. And it gives the same answer. Simply modifying the sort to not reversed does not give much speedup.

```
import random
import time
from bisect import insort
from heapq import heapify, heapreplace
from math import ceil

def makelist(num_elements):
    mylist = range(int(num_elements))
    mylist = list(mylist)
    for i in mylist:
        mylist[i] = int(random.random()*100)

    return mylist

def minSum(num, k):
    for i in range(k):
        num.sort(reverse=True)
        num.insert(0, ceil(num[0] / 2))
        num.remove(num[1])
    return sum(num)

def minSum2(num, k):
    last_idx = len(num) - 1
    for i in range(k):
        num.sort()
        num[last_idx] = ceil(num[last_idx] / 2)
    return sum(num)

def min_sum(num, k):
    num.sort()
    for i in range(k):
        largest = num.pop()
        insort(num, ceil(largest/2))
    return sum(num)

def min_heap(num, k):
    for i in range(len(num)):
        num[i] = -num[i]
    heapify(num)
    for i in range(k):
        largest = num[0]
        heapreplace(num, largest // 2)
    return -sum(num)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mylist = makelist(1e4)
    k = len(mylist) + 1
    t0 = time.time()
    # we have to make a copy of mylist for all of the functions
    # otherwise mylist will be modified
    print('minSum: ', minSum(mylist.copy(), k))
    t1 = time.time()
    print('minSum2: ', minSum2(mylist.copy(), k))
    t2 = time.time()
    print('min_sum: ', min_sum(mylist.copy(), k))
    t3 = time.time()
    print('min_heap: ', min_heap(mylist.copy(), k))
    t4 = time.time()        

    print()
    print('time for each method for k = %.0e: ' % k)
    print('minSum: %f sec' % (t1-t0))
    print('minSum2: %f sec' % (t2-t1))
    print('min_sum: %f sec' % (t3-t2))
    print('min_heap: %f sec' % (t4-t3))
```

and here is console output:

```
minSum:  205438
minSum2:  205438
min_sum:  205438
min_heap:  205438

time for each method for k = 1e+04:
minSum: 2.386861 sec
minSum2: 2.199656 sec
min_sum: 0.046802 sec
min_heap: 0.015600 sec

------------------
(program exited with code: 0)

Press any key to continue . . .
```